# how to change the date format with out Using SimpleDateFormater class in java

Tags: java

Change the date format with out using `SimpleDateFormat` class object in java
without using above code, is there any **alternative in java**?

Comment: why do u wanna do that.?

Comment: Sounds like "how to tighten a screw without a screw driver"

Comment: Write your own class to format date.

Comment: Your question sounds as if you do not know what you are doing and you just have a rough idea what a possible solution could be. Explain more so we can help you find out what a good solution is in this case.

Comment: Did you google for alternatives?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `System.out.format` with `%tB` `%te` etc.

Have a look the Java tutorial [example](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberformat.html).

```
  Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
  System.out.format("%tB %te, %tY%n", c, c, c); // -->  "May 29, 2006"
  System.out.format("%tl:%tM %tp%n", c, c, c);  // -->  "2:34 am"
  System.out.format("%tD%n", c);    // -->  "05/29/06"
```